# How to fix error: [BEA][SQLServer JDBC Driver]No more data available to read

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My java application does use DB Connection pooling. One of the functionality started failing today with this error:
[BEA][SQLServer JDBC Driver]No more data available to read

This doesn't occur daily. Once I restart my application server things look fine for some days and this error comes back again.

Anyone encountered this error? Reasons might vary, but I would like to know those various reasons to mitigate my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the database or network connection has briefly had an outage? You might expect any currently open result sets then to become invalid with resulting errors.

I've never seen this particular error, but then I don't work with BEA or SQL Server, but a quick google does show other folks suggesting such a cause.

When you're using a connection pool, if you do get such a glitch, then all connections in teh pool become "stale" or invalid. My application server (WebSphere) has the option to discard the entire connection pool after particular errors are detected. The result then is that one unlucky request sees the error, but then subsequent requests get a new connection and recover. If you don't discard the whole pool then you get a failure as each stale connection is used and discarded.

I suggest you investigate to see a). whether your app server has such a capability b). how you application responds if the database is bounced, if this replicates the error then maybe you've found the cause.

Comment: thnq. I did some 'Google'ing as well. And yeah what you mentioned seem like possible reasons. One way to handle stale or invalid connections on WebLogic is to set up the Test Frequencty seconds to 1, so that WebLogic tests the connections every one second and replaces any stale ones with new ones.

I was looking if there could be other reasons too. Someone who might have experienced this error may be !!!